# Can I use LLVM to accelerate a build and reduce GCC compile time?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, llvm

I am trying to reduce the compile time for `HHVM` which can take two hours.

I read somewhere that `LLVM` can act as a preprocessor to `gcc` and greatly reduce memory use and compile time?

Unfortunately I cannot seem to compile `HHVM` directly with `clang` as I get strange fatal errors like `'array' file not found` even though I tried setting the `CXXFLAGS` to `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` mode, no luck.

I've read about `dragonegg` but not sure how to use it or if it is what I am looking for?

Comment: I think it should work with clang, at least here there are some clang fixes: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/pull/2905

Comment: Can you show the exact errors you get? I guess using clang directly would be much easier than the other possibilities.

Comment: `c11` and `gnu11` are C dialects, not C++. You want `c++11` or `gnu++11`.

Comment: @sepp2k sorry I said it incorrectly, I tried `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: @JanRüegg your comment specifically helped me if you want to break it out into an answer? The solution was [in that patch that facebook never applied](https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm/commit/2df746749fcb74c405cdd132650b99a5711595b9) to HHVM, you have to remove `-stdlib=libc++` from `HPHPCompiler.cmake`. I am still compiling under clang but it has gotten much, much farther than it did before barfing the last few times I tried to make it work.

Comment: @Davidbrcz ccache can reduce re-compile time but not if there are lots of updates like HHVM has?

Comment: Install `libc++` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, I think working with clang directly would be much easier. So try to find out why clang is not working for the project, and find patches / fixes for this.

For example, applying [this patch](https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm/commit/2df746749fcb74c405cdd132650b99a5711595b9) might be a good start.

Comment: That was it, at least it is getting me much much farther, essentially  remove `-stdlib=libc++` from  `HPHPCompiler.cmake`. Facebook never applied the patch. Will mark as answer if the compile actually finishes. Even with clang it is taking an hour so far.

Comment: Ah drats, it got much further but broke on libgd `hhvm/hphp/runtime/ext/gd/libgd/gd_webp.cpp:75:20: error: expected ')'` and `hhvm/hphp/runtime/ext/gd/libgd/gd_webp.cpp:75:10: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'unsigned int' loses information
                temp = (unsigned uint8*) gdRealloc(filedata, size+GD_WEBP_ALLOC_STEP);`  I wonder if it just a bug in the trunk.

Comment: Now experimenting with making it a non-fatal error with `Wno-error`

Answer (score 2):

`dragonegg` is a LLVM code generation plugin for gcc, so it's the other way around from what you're looking for.

I'm not aware of a way to plug Clang in the front of gcc that's supported these days. That said, if you can build a project with gcc, it shouldn't be hard to build it with Clang. Even the Linux kernel can be built with Clang these days with some minor patches. It's very likely that the HVVM developers build it with Clang as well, and they may have some patches for that.

But the answer to the question in the title is no.

Answer (score 2):

> I read somewhere that LLVM can act as a preprocessor to gcc

I think that what you read was literally about pre-processing. Indeed, I myself vaguely remember someone calling Clang's pre-processor faster than GCC's. Unfortunately for us, your answer does not provide the link to your source of information, so it is impossible to check what the actual claim was.

You can pre-process your C files with `clang -E file.c -o file.i`. After this, you can compile `file.i` with GCC, and GCC will be able to omit its (supposedly slower) pre-processor. Unfortunately for you, pre-processing is the easiest step of the compilation of a C file, and I doubt it accounts for more than 3% of the total time, meaning that even halving the time taken by pre-processing will at best improve compilation time by 1.5%.

I do not see any other language, common between the two compilation suites, than pre-processed C that could be output from Clang to be fed into GCC in order to speed up anything.